# Method to handle exceptions in a async block to cannot convert return object to to async method return type

Tags: c#, async-await

I have implemented a method to handle exceptions around a async block like below:

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<T>> RetryTest<T>(Func<Task<ServiceResponse<T>>> method)
    {
        try
        {
            return await method.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return FormatExceptionResponse<T>(exception);
        }
    }
```

And use it to wrap async code like:

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<DataJob>> Insert(DataJob entity)
    {

        return await RetryTest<ServiceResponse<DataJob>>(async () =>
        {
            Context.AddObject("DataJobs", entity);
            DataServiceResponse responses = await Context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return new ServiceResponse<DataJob>((HttpStatusCode)responses.Last().StatusCode, entity);

        });

    }
```

However the last return statement has an error: Cannot convert expression type ServiceResponse to async method return type ServiceResponse.

Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: Note there's no reason for `Insert` to be marked `async`; you can just return the result of `RetryTest` directly and not need to mark the method as `async`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of `RetryTest` accepts a `T` and then returns a `ServiceResponse<T>`

When you call it you've supplied: `ServiceResponse<DataJob>` as `T`, so the return type of `RetryTest`, since it needs to wrap`T` in a `ServiceResponse`, should return a `ServiceResponse<ServiceResponse<DataJob>>` rather than a `ServiceResponse<DataJob>`.  (You're not returning that, hence the error.)

You simply want to pass `DataJob` as the generic argument to `RetryTest` instead of `ServiceResponse<DataJob>`.

Or, better yet, just remove the generic arguments entirely when calling `RetryTest` and let them be inferred properly, and then you can't mess it up.

Comment: Oh I had missed that generic argument. Thanks Servy!